# Is there No Way to Detect Routed URL in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

Is there no way to detect if the current request is being mapped via ASP.NET 4.0 URL routing?

I have an HTTP module that handles the application's `BeginRequest` event. I have found that this handler is called for all file types, including CSS, JS, image files, etc., and I just want to perform an action if the target file is an ASPX page.

In the case of routed pages, all the properties of the `HttpRequest` object reflect the requested URL, and not the ASPX page that the request is being mapped to. How can I determine if the request will be handled by an ASPX file?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the Begin Request event a Handler has not been defined for the specific URL.

So there is no way of determining what will actually end up handling that URL because IIS has yet to decide.  That happens after Begin Request has been fired, that is why all file types are being called.

That's one of the reasons why Begin Request is not a good event to really execute code on that needs to target specifically .NET files.  A good use for the Begin Request method is adding cookies or headers to either a request or response.  Those can be tacked on without a problem no matter what ends up handling the request.

As mentioned before I would suggest a Base Class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page that all your other pages inherit from, or create a Master page.

Now without specifically knowing what you are trying to do it's hard to give a good solution.  It may be possible to test a URL to check if it'll be fired by a Route, but I don't know how and it also seems excessive when you can handle it through a base class or master page.

Comment: That appears to be the correct answer (unfortunately). What I'm trying to do is implement HTTP compression. I've been researching this for some time and nothing I've found works reliably. I've got it working somewhat from the HTTP handler I described. However, the handler gets called for every file type. I need to determine if the request is for a page. Since routed URLs have no extension, how can I tell?

Comment: Put your HTTP Module further down in the application life-cycle
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx
Anything after PostMapRequestHandler should give you some indication inside of the context as to what Handler will be used to execute the request.

Comment: I tried PreRequestHandlerExecute but, to my surprise, members like `Request.PhysicalPath` *still* show the unrouted URL. However, it looks like Request.RequestContext.RouteData.RouteHandler.VirtualPath does, in fact, refer to the target page. In my case, "~/Listing.aspx". Perhaps that's workable. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird like that.  Even within the actually ASPX page code behind Request.PhyscialPath will still point to the assumed physical path based on the URL.  My thought was originally more along the lines of using HttpContext.Current.Handler.  It will give you some information about what class will actually be handling the request and should also be always present where RouteData will be null if it's not routed, but it may be a bit more difficult to use/understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a BasePage as a base class for all pages in the application, and handle the Page_Load event there instead of using an HTTP module.

Comment: Thanks. But I *really* hope that is not necessary.